# Is daily upvote reputation tracked separately from daily cap-exempt reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Question is in the title.  For example:

If I get 15 people to accept my answers and 0 upvotes, I will be at 225 rep

If I then get one upvote, will I get any reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will.

They are not tracked separately, but reputation gained from accepting an answer, getting an answer accepted, being awarded a bounty and the association bonus does not count towards the daily rep cap.

This is all detailed in [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)